# How to prevent malware infection and file accessibility through a wireless router?

Tags: network, windows, attacks, malware, wireless

**The answer suggested in the 'duplicate' is about a different issue**. But since my original wording of the question seems to have not been clear - here's a second attempt:

Is there any danger of any of my computer's files being read or changed (mainly - infected by malware) in the following scenario:

- I have file sharing turned off (in "advanced sharing settings").
- I connect to a public wireless network (such as at a restaurant), and
  surf the web.

**Assuming**:
No vulnerabilities are exploited on the web browser (or its plugins etc.).

This is a question about dangers of connecting to the router itself. Can someone on the same network access my computer?

This is *not* about anyone sniffing my passwords or what websites I'm visiting. Let's assume I just Google "StackExchange" and then disconnect. Is that safe?

Comment: Duplicate? Not at all. Read the question there.

Comment: This question has been answered many times here... Sorry for the link

Comment: @BrianAdkins This question isn't really a duplicate of the linked one. If you know another question that *is* a duplicate, please post the link here.

Comment: similar question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34764/is-there-any-security-threat-with-open-wifi-connection

Comment: So, the router is your endpoint, not some website on the internet?

Comment: @Marcel I don't understand your comment. My point in the last paragraph of the question is to stop getting irrelevant links which deal with internet privacy. (That's why I edited my question to include this, even though I think my question is clear even without it.)

Comment: The first and only step required to do this is to file disable sharing within the operating system. Of course if the network does not use encryption, then all all internet traffic is published, to anyone connected to the network.

Comment: @Ramhound So if I have "network discovery", "file sharing", etc. all turned off (in the "advanced sharing settings") there's no risk? If so - you can transform your comment into an answer. Assuming you're correct - that's the answer.

Comment: @ispiro - I am correct but I refuse to post an answer where I suggest you simply "don't share your files with the network" since that is self explainatory solution.

Comment: @Marcel Now I understand your comment's question. The answer is yes (if I understood correctly). My question has now been edited to clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a public network, you don't know who else is connected.

The problems in this kind of network aren't only the attackers, but also malwares and viruses, as you said.

For example, many users aren't able to figure out if their computer is infected, and they connect in public networks with the result of infect them inadvertently.

The only way to avoid these dangers, IMHO, is to install a good "Internet Security", with a complete protection from viruses, malwares, trojans, spam, hackers, etc.

PS: I'm sorry for my bad English